# will lack of experience make it impossible to change my subject of study?

Tags: phd, changing-fields

I'm 33 years old and I have my master's in physics from a relatively good university in my country.

I have 6 years working experience as a foreign commercial executive which I hated every minute of it, but I needed to make some money. I have to add that I have visited different factories in different countries during the missions I went.

About two years ago, I resigned and diligently went for learning everything about electronics and microelectronics which were always my desire. Now, I feel quite confident in embedded systems programming and everyday I study so hard whatever related to digital electronics but I have not yet applied for a job in this field.

I know this is what I always wanted.
I have average grades in university and good GRE.

What are my chances to get admission for PhD in electronic engineering in one of US universities?

Comment: Actually we have a question about the age and academic admissions which may help you with first part of your question: [I want to do research but I'm too old for a PHD](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/i-want-to-do-research-but-im-too-old-for-a-phd/24582#24582). I think it would be better to narrow your question and focus on the second part which is about experience and I did not find a question about it on website.

Answer (score 1):

Age won't matter much.

"Experience" may matter. Any program has prerequisites, and there's really no way to jump to PhD without that essential knowledge.

I don't think you're going to get into the PhD program without first getting a Masters or having equivalent work experience. The Physics background plus independent study *may* be able get you into a Masters program.

I suspect you'll have better odds if you do the Masters in your own country, and then apply for a PhD program (in the US or elsewhere).